# Make vim follow symlinks when opening files from command line

Tags: linux, macos, vim, zsh

I'm a huge vim lover, but I can't find a way to get vim to follow symlinks when opening files.

As an example, all the dotfiles in my home dirs are symlinked to within the .zprezto directory:

```
.vimrc -> ~/.zprezto/runcoms/vimrc
.zshrc -> ~/.zprezto/runcoms/zshrc
```

I'm keeping my fork of .zprezto in a private git repo, which is then used to keep all my Mac/Linux machines and servers in sync. Whenever I'm editing any of these files in vim, none of the plugins I'm using for git management work properly, because the symlink I'm accessing when calling `vim ~/.zshrc` is outside the git repo. Is there any way of forcing vim to follow the link and open up the actual file when I open it from the command line, so that the buffer is then in the git repo?

Tried this:

```
function vim() {
  local ISLINK=`readlink $1`
  /usr/local/bin/vim ${ISLINK:-$1}
}
```

but it didn't work as well as I'd hoped as it limits me to one file with no options. I'd like to know if there's a more sensible way of doing this before I go about write a massive wrapper function that can take all edge cases into account.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Vim seems to follow symlinks just fine here.

Comment: Maybe dumb, but why not run `vim ~/.zprezto/runcoms/zshrc` instead? Also, this Q&A might be related (assuming I understand your question correctly): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708700/getting-the-logical-path-in-vim-when-theres-a-symlink

Comment: @DanCornilescu Saw that link before I posted the question - that works well when in a symlinked directory, but doesn't for editing a symlinked file. Calling `vim ~/.zprezto/runcoms/zshrc` works well, but the files aren't in that directory on each machine, whereas the symlinks live at `~/.zshrc` on all machines. It means I can run `vim ~/.zshrc` on any machine using this git repo, and still get the file I want, rather than having to work out the location of the repo on the machine first.

Comment: @lcd047 it follows the symlink fine and opens the file, but the location of the buffer in vim is the location of the *symlink* rather than the *physical file*, meaning that as far as the buffer is concerned it is not in the git repo, but in the home directory.

Comment: Maybe try to move the config git repos in the same place on all machines? Unless you really, really want to write that massive wrapper :)

Comment: I use a similar technique of symlinks from ~/.zshrc to a real file in a git repo, but I just use command line git from the repo directory instead of any git plugins in vim.

Comment: related, just for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794611/how-to-expand-a-symbolic-link-to-the-full-path-of-a-filename-in-vim

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So it doesn't look like there's anything built into vim to allow this. I had a play with the wrapper function and it turned out to be a little easier than I thought. Here's the final result:

```
function vim() {
  args=()
  for i in $@; do
    if [[ -h $i ]]; then
      args+=`readlink $i`
    else
      args+=$i
    fi
  done

  /usr/local/bin/vim -p "${args[@]}"
}
```

Just add to your `.zshrc` (or config file for your favorite shell) to use it.

Comment: Nice one.  What exactly does the -h in [[ -h $i ]] do?  Also what could I google to find more of those?

Answer (score 2):

There's a Vim [plugin](https://github.com/aymericbeaumet/vim-symlink) called vim-symlink that allows you to automatically follow the symlinks when you open a file.